# why $facebook->getUser() return 0?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

My code is

```
include_once "fbaccess.php";

  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
  var_dump($user_id); 
  var_dump($facebook);
```

Result:-

```
int(0)       // Why $user_id return zero

object(Facebook)#1 (7) { 
      ["appId":protected]=> string(15) "4545454" 
      ["appSecret":protected]=> string(32) "323232" 
      ["user":protected]=> int(0) 
      ["signedRequest":protected]=> NULL 
      ["state":protected]=> string(32) "c8d6e657da34596785b06e7511921529" 
      ["accessToken":protected]=> string(48) "{APP_SECRET}" 
      ["fileUploadSupport":protected]=> bool(false) }
```

Please help me. Which thing i have missed????

Comment: Are not you supposed to start a session or something?

Comment: has the user (or you) clicked the login url? is this the callback handler already?

Comment: Don't ever show you App secret in public!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted and stick to the given example. The code you posted is incomplete and will not work like this.